# Google oauth2 get userdetails not working and hanging php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I copied this from the test folder included in the php sdk. It redirects to google for authentication as expected but when calling `$oauth2->userinfo->get()` it just hangs there. The cloud console said **the error was 400** but I don't see what I could be doing wrong.

I updated the setting as per what is on my page. I've been searching for an answer for 2 hours. Please help :(

```
        /* OAuth settings */
        $clientID = 'blahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        $clientSecret = 'secret';
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $developerKey = 'key';

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Study-Corner");
        $client->setClientId($clientID);
        $client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
        $client->setDeveloperKey($developerKey);
        $oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);

        if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

            // get the access token
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

            // redirect back
            header('Location: '. filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            return;
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
            // set the access token
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        }

        /* check if we have access */
        if($client->getAccessToken()) {
            $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

            // These fields are currently filtered through the PHP sanitize filters.
            // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
            $email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $img = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

            print $email;

            // The access token may have been updated lazily.
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        } else {
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            header("Location: ".$authUrl);
            die;
        }
```

Comment: I think you can not define the Authentication scope

Comment: I don't know what you mean but I tried it with an older application details and it worked perfectly. Anything new that is created is not working...

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

Add `$client->setScopes('profile);`  to your client details.